# Having issues adding an onclick event to theme widget button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, widget

I'm having an issue with an onclick() event not firing with a menu item button. This button isn't in the standard menu, it's added to the menu through the widget area so I can't really edit the anchor tag. The button, once clicked, is supposed to bring up a Scheduler.

Menu button in question "Request Service":

[image]

Here is the widget area and my options:

[image]

Here is what happens when the event is working properly.

[image]

I've tried to target the class of the button using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.btButtonWidgetLink').click(function() {
            onclick="ScheduleEngine.show()";
        });
    });
```

When I do the inspector in Chrome, it's not showing up in the anchor tag. I added the above code using the plugin "Custom CSS & JS."

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Both comments answered my question correctly.
Correct code:
`$('a.btButtonWidgetLink').click(function() { ScheduleEngine.show(); });`

Comment: You´re doing it wrong: the `onclick` bit as you have it on your code is meant to be used with HTML tags, not inside JS code (or at least not the way you're doing it now.) What you actually need is the `ScheduleEngine.show()` part (without the double quotes.) See [onclick Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You'll have to pardon my ignorance, but are you saying instead of writing onclick="ScheduleEngine.show()" I should be writing it like this: onclick=ScheduleEngine.show()?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you only need to write `ScheduleEngine.show()` inside the callback function. The `onclick=` part isn't needed (and not even valid JS code :P).

Comment: `$('a.btButtonWidgetLink').click(function() { ScheduleEngine.show(); });`

Comment: Ah ok haha. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add this code in the **footer** of your theme:

```js
<script> 
    jQuery("a#ScheduleEngine").bind("click", function() {
        ScheduleEngine.show();
    });
</script>
```